# Is there any way to debug lambda function with s3 trigger locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to debug my application by breakpoints and this lambda function is triggered by uploading to `s3 bucket`. Is there any way to debug locally with breakpoints without making the request by hand ? As it is really slow to deploy and test by printing the values.

I am using python for this (but probably it does not matter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Serverless framework, you can test the s3 event locally with:

```
sls invoke local -f yourFunction -p ./testEvent.json
```

For that you need to create a mock s3 event and save to a file (in this case named testEvent.json). To create such a mock s3 event, you can customise the [Amazon S3 Event example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html), to suite your needs. Or you can log your real s3 event from the deployed lambda function and copy it from there.

You then save the event to a file (for example testEvent.json) and invoke your function with the command above.

Comment: since I have not tried it yet, what about the context is it the same as online ?

Comment: the context is pretty much the same as online, serverless write that they "mock the context with simple mock data." (https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/invoke) but in my case some of the parameters are set to their real value so it's not completely made up.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `sam local generate-event` [command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-generate-event.html) from SAM cli? The command below shows how to generate a JSON file that you can then pass to the local invoke command to trigger the local function.

```sh
sam local generate-event s3 put --bucket bucket-name --key key-name > event_file.json
```

Then you invoke your function with the payload:

```sh
sam local invoke function-name -e event_file.json
```

Comment: Can I use this with the serverless-framework [ https://www.serverless.com/ ], as it looks harder to do it this way

Comment: To be honest, harder is contextual to consuming parties bro! I am also not an expert at using serverless framework so i wouldn't be able to provide advise on that! Hope you find the answer somewhere though! @rev-kid